# How to move routines from project source to library

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, reference

I have written some routines in my project and since only after have found them to be useful for other projects want now to move them to library. My language is C# WPF.
What I have done therefore is to make a new project:

[image]

and add it to my Solution with the name of Helper

[image]

then I have looked for all the using in the original project and added them to the library but noticed that some where in gray colour.

So I tried to add all the references that were in the original project and added them to the library. That being said there still are tons of errors.
I'd say they are related to graphics or perhaps I have added a wrong kind of library not related to C# WPF (see attached previous image).

Following some of the errors
Thanx

[image]

---EDIT---
@Stefan Wuebbe first of all I know that gray namespace are the ones that are not used. But since I'm moving the same routines from primal project to library I assume that there should be the same namespaces. So if some are in gray some of them are not used. And they are not used since the project hasn't got the right references.

As for adding them e.g. I can't find the System.Windows.Media (see pic)

[image]

Comment: have you tried to add namespaces for file, which has error?

Comment: My bad for not mentioning. Of course I did, the same one taken from the primal project

Comment: But they are grayed and so they are not used since there are not the correct references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Class Library" project template is a sparse one - if you want to have "visual" elements in your library, you could use a different template like "Classic Desktop" -> "WPF User Control Library".

The difference however would be the default "References" - so an alternate way could be adding required references to the project you already created, where for example the `SolidColorBrush` belongs the `System.Windows.Media` namespace which is in the `PresentationCore` assembly.

(As for the namespaces in gray color: those are unused namespaces that the code in the current CS file would not need currently.)

**Added:** Apparently there are four assembly References that a "WPF User Control Library" Project by default has, and a "Class Library" Project has not in its "References" node: `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework`, `System.Xaml`, `WindowsBase`

Comment: Ok I'll answer all your points. Thanks for helping first of all. Then pls see my EDIT above

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to add it as a WPF user control library. I'll let you know

Comment: That worked thanx. It would be interesting to know why the second solution (adding references manually) didn't work.

Comment: You are welcome, and I'd also be curios why adding manually did not work - sometimes the names are not very obvious IMO, for example the `System.Windows.Media` Namespace being in the `PresentationCore` Assembly (instead of a hypothetical `System.Windows.Media` assembly), whereas the `System.Windows.Forms` Assembly belongs to the "Windows Forms" UI sub-system